# Purchase a domain name for static web applications

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have deployed a static web application (Gatsby) now I want purchase a domain. If the web was deployed to Azure App Service there is some instructions on how to do that. But for static web applications the "custom domain" button gives different options. For a Static Web Site I see
[image: Static Web Application]
For an App Service web application I see
[image]
So how do I add/purchase a custom domain for a static web appication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Document reference:

You can refer to [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain) to solve your issue.

***Steps:***

**Step 1.**

Search `App Service Domain` when create new services, and create it.

[image]

**Step 2.**

Search and select the available domain, fill in the information and click create.

[image]

**Step 3.**

Click `Advanced Management Portal` to management DNS.

[image]

**Step 4.**

Search your domain, and click Manage DNSSEC DS Record.

[image]

**Step 5.**

Change Nameservers, choose recommand options. Let Azure host it. After modify, it should be like below screenshot.

[image]

**Step 6.**

Add `Records`.

You can get value from static webapp.

[image]

And modify default Name of `www` info, iuput it in `Advanced Management Portal`.

[image]

[image]

**Step 7.**

Then you need `Validate custom domain` in azure static web app.

[image: Validate custom domain]

**After Configure, you can use your custom domain to visit your webapp.**

[image]