# Create an A record for a VM in azure

Tags: azure, cname, a-records, azure-dns

I have a VM running in azure with a `public ip` address and the required firewall settings and network security groups.

I want to create an alias for this vm such as `www.abc.com`.

I created an A record for it with `@` as the name and `public-ip` as the value but I am still getting the error that the server's ip address cannot be found. I am out of ideas.

Here is an image to illustrate how I have created the `A record`
[image: A record for VM's public-ip]

Here is an image showing the error
[image: Error]

Comment: You have to check with your domain name registrar to change the nameservers to use azure nameservers.

Comment: [There are complete steps in this post, you can refer to it and check again.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478958/purchase-a-domain-name-for-static-web-applications/63497561#63497561)

Comment: just to use proper wording: What you want to create is an "A record", not an alias, aka "CName"

Comment: What is the situation now? Do you solve the problem or need more help?

Comment: No. I went ahead with a load balancer instead.